# Not able to copy any folder from samba share network

Tags: 13.04, networking, nautilus

I am connected to a windows network and i am coping a directory from my windows share, it starts coping but the progress bar stops in the middle without any error message and it does not copy.

But i am able to copy single files through same folder without any pause..but when i select more than two files and try to paste them in my desktop they got stop in the middle.

Any solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you specify the total size of the data after which the copying stops?
Also you can use the following:

```
mount -t smbfs -o lfs //server/share /localdir
```

lfs tag allows transfer of large files

Comment: If there is 10 files then it will stop in first file.